# what address to use for remote login on my Mac

Tags: networking, ssh, mac

I'm sure this question is basic but I have tried to search for how to do this and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have macOS Monterey 12.0.1.  I have Remote Login enabled. I have "Allow full disk access" checked and Remote Login is enabled for All Users. When I go to this pane in System Preferences it says 'To log in to this computer remotely, type “ssh katie@192.168.0.47”.'  But this is a local ip.  I want an ip I can use to login remotely.  When I type "what's my ip" into google I get an ip, but I can't ping it from the other machine; there's 100% packet loss.  When I type ifconfig at my Mac's terminal I get a bunch of output I don't understand, but none of it looks like a public ip. How can I log in to my machine?

Per comments, some more information: the other computer is a PC.  It is outside my home/network.  The basic task I want to accomplish is large directory transfer, which I can't manage with with remote screen sharing program I have set up between the two machines, dwservice.net

Comment: “But this is a local ip. I want an ip I can use to login remotely.” - Are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: Your router/modem IP will be the one you use and you will need to configure the router to allow the ports to be forwarded to that machine.  When you go to "what's my ip" you will see the IP addr of your cable/dsl/whatever modem.  Your router can do that magic to make that avail to you.  192.168.x.x tells me that you are inside of the router.

Comment: @Ramhound how would I know if I were?

Comment: How remote is 'remote'? You mean from outside the building, or just inside. From inside, then the 192.x address is fine. From outside you might be better off using Screen Sharing, which doesn't need you to be able to 'find' the other Mac out there in the world, you can ask for it by Apple ID & it will 'jump' though the firewall/CGNAT to meet you halfway.

Comment: @Tetsujin the other computer, outside my building, is a Windows PC, and I'm already using a screen sharing application.  The problem is that I want to be able to rsync large directories between the two computers, and the free remote shell program I'm using does not permit that.

Comment: Ah, OK. You should mention that in your question. Screen Sharing [.app] is Mac>Mac only.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation should help you get setup to use remote desktop from an external network (WAN)

https://support.apple.com/guide/remote-desktop/nat-router-guidelines-apd78601556/3.9.6/mac/11.5.1

https://support.apple.com/guide/remote-desktop/add-clients-apdc285b269/3.9.6/mac/11.5.1

Find info on how to forward ports on your router here: https://portforward.com/how-to-port-forward/

Once you have your router configured go to https://whatsmyip.com/ and get your Public IPv4 address.

From there you can use ssh to connect for easy access, or you can look through the documentation for other options. Also take not of the "Security with Remote Desktop" section.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Given my living situation if solving this involves logging in to my router I realistically need to address my problem some other way.  It might make more sense to try to fix remote access on the remote PC, because ironically I have friendlier access to the router there.  I can still use the concepts/context to work on exposing the port on the other machine.

Comment: Would one of the many remote desktop software solutions like Chrome Remote Desktop or LogMeIn work for your situation?

Comment: I'm using one of them, dwservice.net, but I want to transfer large files, syncing directories, and it doesn't let me do that.